# How can I get a unique ID for a 2d array?

Tags: c#, algorithm, multidimensional-array

I want a way to get a unique ID for a 2d array.
for example:

Array A:

```
[4,2,3]
[4,5,6]
[7,8,9]
```

Array B:

```
[9,2,3]
[4,5,6]
[1,1,9]
```

I want a function to know that A<>B without save whole A and whole B.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you need to generate a unique hash, or simply a way to tell arrays apart? Your title and question text suggest different questions...

Comment: Is the position of integers important ?

Comment: What are minimum and maximum value for elements in array?

Comment: @Dialecticus: Not specidied, unsigned integer values.

Comment: @Homam: Hashes aren't unique, pretty much by definition. The only way of making it genuinely unique is to avoid losing information, at which point it's pretty pointless to call it a hash.

Comment: What's your array data format? are arbitrary or all of them are bellow i.e 10?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, to get a guaranteed *unique* value, you *will* effectively have to save the complete contents of the array. You could use a hash which would tell you if one array is *possibly* the same as another, but you can't get uniqueness without having a lossless transformation.

As an example of a simple hashing function:

```
int hash = 17;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    hash = hash * 31 + array[i, j];
  }
}
return hash;
```

Now, two different arrays will *very probably* have a different hash - but they might not.

How much space are you willing to spend on the ID, and how big is each value in the array? The more information you're willing to put in the ID, the less likely you are to get false positives... until you get to the stage where the ID is as big as the array, at which point you can ensure that you'll have *no* false positives, of course.

Answer (score 1):

```
 public static long computeHash(int[][] array) {

        final int p = 16777619; 
        long hash = 2166136261l;

        for(int i = 0; i< array.length; i++) {
           for(int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
               hash = (hash ^ array[i][j] ^ (i * j)) * p; 
           }
        }

        hash += hash << 13;
        hash ^= hash >> 7;
        hash += hash << 3;
        hash ^= hash >> 17;
        hash += hash << 5;

        return hash;

    }
```

About hash function: [here](http://bretm.home.comcast.net/~bretm/hash/6.html)